# Scipy cluster binary data and label

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm trying to do a k-means clustering on a binary data set. Following matrix is based on web page access('1' for access and '0' for not access). First column is a label to identify each user.

```
0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0
1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0
2,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1
3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0
4,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0
5,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
6,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0
7,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0
8,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
9,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0
```

I'm using scipy k-means and followed [this](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html) tutorial. Finally I want to know to which cluster each user belongs to. Ex: if k = 3

```
0 - cluster_1
1 - cluster_0
2 - cluster_1
3 - cluster_3
.. - ....
```

Following is what I have tried and it seems binary data is not properly clustered. Can this be improved to get my expected output?

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import vstack,array
from numpy.random import rand
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq

# data generation
data = np.array([[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]])

centroids,_ = kmeans(data,2)
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'or')
plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read more documentation, don't only copy and paste code from the net.

```
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
```

Have you looked at what `idx` is?